# How can I create an OLS Regression Summary without getting this error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression, statsmodels

I have a simple pandas dataframe that I'm looking to see if I can run a regression analysis on different variables to see if it affects wine quality. The dataset I'm using is from kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009

Here is the relevant code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('wine.csv')

independent_variables = [['fixed acidity', 'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', \
                        'chlorides', 'free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', \
                         'pH', 'sulphates', 'alcohol']]
independent_variables = sm.add_constant(independent_variables)
dependent_variable= df['quality']
regression_model= sm.OLS(dependent_variable,independent_variables).fit()


print(regression_model.summary())
```

```
The error is shown below:

UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[89], line 4
      1 independent_variables = [['fixed acidity', 'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', \
      2                         'chlorides', 'free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', \
      3                          'pH', 'sulphates', 'alcohol']]
----> 4 independent_variables = sm.add_constant(independent_variables)
      5 dependent_variable= df['quality']
      6 regression_model= sm.OLS(dependent_variable,independent_variables).fit()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py:270, in add_constant(data, prepend, has_constant)
    267 elif x.ndim > 2:
    268     raise ValueError('Only implemented for 2-dimensional arrays')
--> 270 is_nonzero_const = np.ptp(x, axis=0) == 0
    271 is_nonzero_const &= np.all(x != 0.0, axis=0)
    272 if is_nonzero_const.any():

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in ptp(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2695, in ptp(a, axis, out, keepdims)
   2693     else:
   2694         return ptp(axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
-> 2695 return _methods._ptp(a, axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:283, in _ptp(a, axis, out, keepdims)
    281 def _ptp(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
    282     return um.subtract(
--> 283         umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims),
    284         umr_minimum(a, axis, None, None, keepdims),
    285         out
    286     )

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'maximum' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U20'), dtype('<U20')) -> None
```

I was expecting to get a standard OLS result to the console. I've used this exact code (only changed column names) on other dataframes without any problems. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `add_constant` requires that only numerical columns are in the dataframe. You have at least one column with strings. Strings cannot be in the regressor matrix for the models in statsmodels. To handle string or categorical it is more convenient to use formulas which adds a constant/intercept by default.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that `sm.add_constants()` expects to be passed a column-ordered design matrix, but you've passed a list of strings (well, a list of list of strings).

I believe what you intended to pass to `sm.add_constants()` was `df[independent_variables[0]]` (ie. the data associated with your list of column names, rather than just the column names by themselves).

Making this change to your example (along with a couple of formatting improvements), gives the working solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm


df = pd.read_csv("wine.csv")

independent_variables = [
    [
        "fixed acidity",
        "volatile acidity",
        "citric acid",
        "residual sugar",
        "chlorides",
        "free sulfur dioxide",
        "total sulfur dioxide",
        "density",
        "pH",
        "sulphates",
        "alcohol",
    ]
]
independent_variables = sm.add_constant(df[independent_variables[0]])
dependent_variable = df["quality"]
regression_model = sm.OLS(dependent_variable, independent_variables).fit()

print(regression_model.summary())
```

Additionally, unless you particularly need your `independent_variables` to be a nested list of strings, I'd just define it as a list of strings, and change `df[independent_variables[0]]` to `df[independent_variables]`. ie.

```py
independent_variables = [
    "fixed acidity",
    "volatile acidity",
    "citric acid",
    "residual sugar",
    "chlorides",
    "free sulfur dioxide",
    "total sulfur dioxide",
    "density",
    "pH",
    "sulphates",
    "alcohol",
]
independent_variables = sm.add_constant(df[independent_variables])
```